# How practical is a low-cost balloon that stays at 14 km with attitude control, carrying a 1 kg payload?

Tags: balloons

How long can a balloon stay at a certain altitude (~14km) and what are the techniques to control the altitude? Are there low-cost ($300) methods to maintain an altitude of 14km for weeks? The foreseen payload would be around 1kg.

Comment: Since someone might 'write a book' on this area, it seems 'too broad' for an SE site. A good tip on 'too broad' is that it includes more than one question. Try to limit each Q&A thread to a single question.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Should I edit this question or make a new one? I would simplify it to: How long can a balloon stay at a certain altitude (~14km) and what are the techniques to control the altitude?

Comment: *"Should I edit this question or make a new one?"* I think you should edit the question down to the lesser question you proposed, then move perhaps one or two of the others to new, separate Q&A threads. See how they go, (answers to one or more might show the idea to be impractical) then ask more questions once those few are answered.

Comment: Hi wuza. I edited the title (and removed some now seemingly obsolete tags) to try to better summarize the question you are asking.

Comment: I voted to close this because as written it doesn't seem to have the slightest relevance to space exploration.  If you left out an important fact that would make it relevant for this site, please edit that in.

Comment: Hi Organic Marble. Can you suggest a stack exchange community where the question would have more relevance?

Comment: disagree on that hold, question have strong connection to communications
see google [loon](http://www.google.com/loon/)
it can be used for good and fast communications with crafts on low orbit, specially CubeSat-like. It may have strong impact on amateurs sattelites.

Comment: @MolbOrg Just because the answer to a question has possible applications to spacecraft does not make the question on topic on Space Exploration. 14 km altitude is well below the cruising altitude of some aircraft, and only a tiny fraction of the distance even to the Kármán line.

Comment: @wuza Consider the [Aviation Stack Exchange](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and perhaps specifically their [aircraft-design](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft-design) tag. I suspect you would need to add details to show prior effort in answering the question yourself, however.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I see your point and OP question is't well made. But it's possible to answer, that particular question, it in such way, which extends our knowledge about possible space exploration.

Comment: I also ask the same question in [Aviation.SE](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25688/how-practical-is-a-low-cost-balloon-that-stays-at-14-km-with-altitude-control-c?noredirect=1#comment61914_25688), where it got rejected as too broad. I am still interested in the answers. So any help to reopen this question is appreciated.